# int&b = a; for gcc vs g++

Tags: gcc

I realised gcc and g++ handle differently for the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    int& b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc returns "parse error before &", while no error is returned by g++.

I once encountered an interview mentioned C and C++ compilers handles differently for int& b.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `&` has no meaning in a C type declaration - in C++, it means the variable will be a reference, but those do not exist in C.

In other words, `int& b = a;` simply isn't valid C code.